# Angular CLI Build prod command not building components in dist folder

Tags: angular, deployment

I have created **Angular CLI** project, Inside of it i have component like `dashboard.component.ts`. When i build project with command `ng build --prod` into dist folder my respective `js` files are not found hence my app is not working.

Please help.

Comment: which version of angular you are using? the command is different for ang6.

Comment: angular 6.0.3 Version

Comment: please try `ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer` for build

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of the CLI, then look in the angular.json file.
You should see an entry for "outputPath": "dist" under Options.

If that is set correctly then `npm run build` or `ng build --aot --prod` should work.

Comment: Thanks Tony and BilzZard I build with both above commands but not finding components respective js file. Is it included inside main.js ?